# Running WZUNZIP.EXE (WinZip command line unzipper) on a machine that doesn't have WinZip installed

Tags: command-line, winzip

I would like to be able to unzip files from the command line (via a batch file in this instance) on a Windows Server 2003 machine that does not have WinZip installed.

It seems that three files are needed:

- WZUNZIP.EXE
- WZCLINE.DLL
- WZCL32.DLL

However, I get the following error when I try to run `WZUNZIP.EXE`:

> ERROR(C:\folder\WZUNZIP.EXE,139): WinZip is not installed.
>   You must install WinZip in order to use the WinZip Command Line Support Add-On

Does WinZip (or just the WinZip command-line add-on) allow deployment via a simple file copy, or does it have to be installed with the full installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org) for this, the [command-line version, specifically](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip).

Extract with this command: 7z.exe e archive.zip

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't need the WinZip GUI, just use [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/).